# What is the preferred approach to EF Core migrations in Azure DevOps?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, ef-core-2.2

I'm looking for a workflow to enable local migrations with EF Core (on a developer instance) and then pushing those migrations incrementally through the process:

- CI/CD Integration for development
- Promoting to staging/integration testing
- Promoting to UAT & warmup
- Deploy to production

Assuming I have at least 3 databases above, how can I isolate and track the pending changes without risking corruption in the event I may need to roll back a change at any step of the process?